# Layout UICollectionViewCells with equal margin

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm currently working on a UICollectionView and try to wrap my head around the following problem.

The layout currently looks like this:

[image]

gray = UICollectionView background color

red = cell background color

green = cell.contentView background color

My goal is that all contentViews have the same margin to each of their sides. With the layout as it is right now, I would have to take all the cells on the right side and reduce the `frame.origin.x` by `5.0f`. But is this really the best solution or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`? If you do you can use the property `sectionInset` to have the effect you want.

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = (id)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5); //top, left, bottom, right
```